# Passing variable from shell script to jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I trigger a shell script from Jenkins, This  scripts get date and export it as a environment(Linux) variable $DATE. I need to use this $DATE inside same Jenkins job. I made job as parameter build. Created a string parameter as DATE value as DATE=$DATE. But it is not working.

Please suggest !!

Comment: It's unclear what you're saying — are you setting `DATE` as a parameter, or are you exporting `DATE` from an "Execute shell" build step?

Comment: Hi There, I am trying to export it from script which is running inside Jenkins job to same Jenkins job.

Comment: EnvInject plugin is having some serious security vulnerability. Now Jenkins is having inbuilt support for this https://stackoverflow.com/a/53430757/1753177

Answer (score 93, accepted):

You mention that you are exporting a `DATE` environment variable in an shell script, which is presumably being started via an "Execute shell" step.

The problem is, once the shell step has completed, that environment is gone — the variables will not be carried over to subsequent build steps.
So when you later try to use the `$DATE` value — whether in another build step, or as a parameter to another job — that particular environment variable will no longer exist.

What you can do instead is use the [EnvInject plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin) to export environment variables during a build.  Variables set up using this plugin will be available to all subsequent build steps.

For example, you could write the `DATE` to a properties field in one build step:

```
echo DATE=$(date +%Y-%m-%d) > env.properties
```

Then you can add an "Inject environment variables for your job" build step, and enter `env.properties` in the "Environment Properties File Path" field.

That way, the `DATE` variable (and anything else in that properties file) will be exported and will be visible to the rest of the build steps.

Comment: Thanks. It is unfortunate that Jenkins doesn't support this functionality by default. What I was trying to find is a better way to automatically output all variables set within a shell script to the properties file in a single command. One of my job needs to create about 15 variables based on directories, filenames, timestamps, etc. I would then need 15 echo commands to output to the properties file. And if I were to add additional variables I would also need to ensure they were being outputted. It would be nice to be able to run a command similar to "env"  which outputs all variables defined.

Comment: It is indeed unfortunate that Jenkins does not support it out of the box. Thanks for this answer.

Comment: It might be better to write `env.properties` to `$WORKSPACE/env.properties` and access `$WORKSPACE/env.properties` while injecting variables.

Answer (score 17):

You could use an assignment statement and sh's returnStdout to get the value in Jenkins without having to write to a properties file.

```
foo = sh(
  returnStdout: true, 
  script: 'date'
)
```

Then later on in the Jenkinsfile you can use $foo like any other variable.

EDIT: This is for a pipeline job, not a freestyle job.

Comment: Thanks, tested today and in the current version it works! One relevant thing, needs to call the variable `foo`, in the script with` env.foo`: D

Comment: If you are using the variable in another shell command then I believe you are correct and need to use the env syntax. However if you are using the output as raw text in Jenkins' Groovy then you can just use `foo`.

Also this applies to any of the shell/PowerShell executors.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.
The solution that worked for me was:

```
env.ABC=bat(returnStdout: true, 
script: '''  @echo off echo abc ''').trim()
```

The .trim() and @echo off is important if you want to reuse the variable in another batch script.