# Modifying environment variables (Properties content) in Jenkins and using it later

Tags: batch-file, jenkins, groovy, dsl

I am writing a job in Jenkins using DSL script (& Groovy) that will generate a job further. In the generated job I want the artefacts after compilation to be stored at `D:\Jen\<CURRENT_MONTH_YEAR>` e.g. `D:\Jen\06_2016`.

So, I declare an environment variable in Jenkins with value `D:\Jen` under *Properties Content* (not by adding a build step *Inject Environment Variable* but the *Properties Content* option before SCM configuration).

Now, in a batch file (using batchFile API in the script) I derive the month and year: `06_2016`.

So, my question is how do I share this value I got in batch file with my environment variable.

Comment: It's not completely clear for me what you exactly mean by: "_generate a job further_" – you create a new Jenkins job? "_artefacts after compilation_" – this new job compiles what? "_derive the month and year_" – derive from where? Please add the code you have written so far to your question.

Comment: in short , how can i modify a declared environment variable in a batch file executed in a jenkins job

Comment: Not possible to change an environment variable in a build step. You can do it before the build itself is starting.

Comment: you can write it to a properties file and then and then inject it to the job. see http://stackoverflow.com/a/30128636/947784