# Extract the value of an environment variable in Jenkins build configuration

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-email-ext

I would like to extract the value of an environment variable and put it in my Editable Email Notification's subject line. I tried with `${ENV,var="MY_ENV_VARIABLE"}`, but that simply returns an empty string in the email subject.

Please note, I'm setting `MY_ENV_VARIABLE` inside my build step (Execute shell) by adding a command `export MY_ENV_VARIABLE="some value"`.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30128636/6676240) helped me. Here's what I did:

1. Removed the `export MY_ENV_VARIABLE=my_value` from my build step.
2. Installed the [Environment Injector Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin) in Jenkins and
   restarted Jenkins.
3. Added a build step "Inject environment variables" in my build configuration and entered the declaration `MY_ENV_VARIABLE=my_value` in the
   "Properties Content" text box.
4. Finally, added `${ENV, var="MY_ENV_VARIABLE"}` in my email's subject in Jenkins.

The email subject now shows the value of `MY_ENV_VARIABLE`.